# How can I prevent installation of my android app by unauthorised users?

Tags: android, installation, apk, android-install-apk, unauthorized

I am developing an android app that should be only installed by some authorized users. How can i prevent the installation of the app by others even if they get the apk of my app.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot prevent the installation.

You, however, may require a password when application starts, and give the password to authorized users only.